# Rails: query execution even with eager load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3, given an `Order` that has many `OrderRows`,

if I call the sum function, I get an unwanted query executed

```
Order.eager_load(:order_rows).find(xxx).order_rows.sum{|x| x.unit_taxed_cents}
OrderRow Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "order_rows".* FROM "order_rows" WHERE "order_rows"."order_id" = XXXX
=> 17900
```

instead, if I use, for example, a map, the additional query is not executed:

```
Order.eager_load(:order_rows).find(xxx).order_rows.inject(0){|sum, r| sum + r.unit_taxed_cents }
=> 17900
```

By definition (http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/Enumerable/sum) the 2 functions should be the same thing

Why doensn't it behave like expected?

Thanks

EDIT:

exploring better what rails does,

```
Order.eager_load(:order_rows).find(xxx).order_rows.method(:sum).source_location
```

returns

```
gems/activesupport-3.2.18/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb
```

the definition of the function is:

```
def sum(identity = 0, &block)
  if block_given?
    map(&block).sum(identity)
  else
    inject(:+) || identity
  end
end
```

hence, I'd expect the same useless additional query if I run

```
Order.eager_load(:order_rows).find(xxx).order_rows.map{|x| x.subtotal_taxed}.sum
```

Instead it doesn't happen, and the behavior is correct

Comment: What is the 'a' variable in your second example? Where do you get it from?

Comment: @born4new Sorry! copy/paste error. corrected

Comment: Which version of rails? I suspect that the underlying issue is that they're not the same - ActiveRecord::Relation has its own implementation of sum

Comment: Do you launch the two in the same rails console instance? Try to start a new console (stop spring) and try the second one first...Does it go to your DB?

Comment: @born4new The behavior is the same also with different instances

Comment: @FrederickCheung Version of rails is 3.2.18. What you say is interesting. But I noticed that `Order.eager_load(:order_rows).find(xxx).order_rows.class` returns `Array`

Comment: Rails used to override the class method. If it were actually an array you wouldn't be able to do order_rows.where(...)

Comment: @FrederickCheung I think you should post it as an answer.